# Getting Desktop path with different system languages in python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, path

I want to use `os.path.join`, but I am pretty confused.

At some part of my program I have:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')
```

But, I want to use `os.path.join` in different Windows computers which have different system languages.

I am looking forward to *"know"* the best way to change the 'Desktop' variable depending on the system language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `winshell` module has has a [`desktop()`](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/special-folders.html#winshell.desktop) function that should return the correct value for any locale:

```
>>> import winshell
>>> winshell.desktop()
'C:\\Users\\cody\\Desktop'
```

Comment: It's not a function of locale. The display name in Explorer is localized, but on disk the default name is just "Desktop". The problem this solves is actually that the desktop directory is independently relocatable to an arbitrary path. Programs should not depend on the default location.

Comment: @eryksun Understood, thanks for the informative clarification.

Comment: Is there a way to do it by using the native modules which python3 have?